# Leaflet adding an offset to marker

Tags: leaflet

I am getting the center of a leaflet feature to show its label.

Then, I am specifying an offset when binding the label so it appears upper and righter.

The thing is that i need to add the offset in the `entryJSON.getBounds().getCenter()` code.

Is there a way of adding an offset in a leaflet latlong object? ( I can imagine something like entryJSON.getBounds().getCenter().offset([-10, -57]) but this is not working...)

```
 var marker = new L.marker(entryJSON.getBounds().getCenter(), { opacity: 0.01 });
 marker.bindLabel('whatever here', {noHide: true, className: "info", offset: [-10, -57] });
```

Comment: Your code does not currently  add the marker to your map. Is there an `.addTo(map)` call somewhere ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The label's offset property works with pixels. A `L.LatLng` object works with coordinates not pixels. What you could do is use the conversion methods of `L.Map` to turn your current coordinate position into a pixel position, change that, and then convert back:

```
var latLng = L.latLng([0,0]);

var point = map.latLngToContainerPoint(latLng);

var newPoint = L.point([point.x - 10, point.y - 57]);

var newLatLng = map.containerPointToLatLng(newPoint);
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/LeNqz8?p=preview

Reference: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-latlngtocontainerpoint

Answer (score 3):

a much more easier one: https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/

```
var greenIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'leaf-green.png',
    shadowUrl: 'leaf-shadow.png',

    iconSize:     [38, 95], // size of the icon
    shadowSize:   [50, 64], // size of the shadow
    iconAnchor:   [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
    shadowAnchor: [4, 62],  // the same for the shadow
    popupAnchor:  [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});
```